# Dart initialization and final, final late

Tags: dart, initialization, final, construction

Hi developers！I'm using Dart for flutter. I'm trying to figure out why the code below doesn't need 'late' or 'final' for its variables. I know what these terms mean, but I'm puzzled about when and where the code is actually starting up, or "initializing".

Can someone break it down for me or give me some examples? I'd really appreciate it!

Thank you !

`

```
class Player {
   final String name;
   String mode; 
//`why we do not need late final or late here? `
   int xp;
   int level;
  
  Player(this.name, this.mode, this.xp, this.level); 

// as we declare variables with **'this'** , we initialized variable? 


  
  void playGame() {
    print("You choose $name, $mode. detail: xp = $xp, play level = $level",);
  }

}


void main() {
  var player = Player("King99", "Wizard",1000, 1); 
`// or initialization happened here?`
  player.playGame();
  var player2 = Player("Queen11", "Wizard", 5000, 3);
  player2.playGame();

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect those variables to be `final` or `late`?  The only time you're *required* to use `final` is if your class has a `const` constructor, which requires that the object be immutable with `final` fields.  There's also no need for those members to be `late` because the `Player` constructor initializes them immediately.

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin ! thank you for the comment ! This is not why I want to add `final` or `late`. I was watching the instructor's video, and he deleted the `final` and `late` when he built up the above code. So I wondered that why `final` and `late` deleted. I want to know more about how `Player` constructor initialized. is it initiallized as we use `String mode;`, `int xp;` and `int level;` (with **semicolons?** ) I guess I am not sure about **where this code exactly initialized**

Comment: `mode`, `xp`, and `level` are meant to be mutable (a player's experience and level can change), so they should not be `final`.  There is no reason for them to be `late`. `late` should be used only when necessary.  All members are initialized when the constructor is invoked.  I recommend reading the Dart language tour, specifically https://dart.dev/language/constructors.